# Calculate cosine similarity against a slice of dataframe that meets a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

Suppose I have a movie data frame like this.

```
       Movie_Id  Dir_Id  Genre            Production_House   Plot
        1231      14      Drama               Columbia      Text blob
        1232      16      Romance             Paramount     Text blob
        1233      14      Thriller            Miramax       Text blob
        1234      15      Comedy              Warner Bros.  Text blob
        1235      16      Romantic Comedy     Paramount     Text blob
        1236      16      Drama               Columbia      Text blob
         .         .      .                       .             .
         .         .      .                       .             .
```

Similarity is calculated on the 'Plot' column. I want to find similar movie to Movie_Id 1232' but I only want to calculate similarity between movies that have the same director ID, which is director 16 in this case. I also want it to be dynamic because if I want to find movies similar to Movie_Id '1234' then I would only want to consider movies from director 15.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
  index = index_from_movie_id(df, movie_id) # this gets index using a function
  director = dir_from_movie_id(df, movie_id) # this gets director ID using a function
  in_dir_df = df[df['Dir_Id'] == director]
  tf_idf_dir = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
  tf_idf_dir_matrix = tf_idf_div.fit_transform(in_dir_df['Plot']);
  cosine_similarity_dir_matrix = cosine_similarity(tf_idf_dir_matrix, tf_idf_dir_matrix)
  similarity_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similarity_dir_matrix[index]))
```

However, I am still getting indices of similar movies from other director ID when I see the similarity scores between the movies using.

```
print(similarity_scores)
```

Given the fact that the cosine similarity matrix was built using only indices of movie ids belonging to the same director ID how is it pulling similar movies belonging to different director_id? Am I calling it wrong when I do this

```
similarity_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_similarity_div_matrix[index]))
```

Is there a way where I can only get indices of similar movies that have the same director ID?

Comment: `cosine_similarity(tf_idf_dir_matrix, tf_idf_dir_matrix)` Doesn't this compute cosine similarity between all movies by a director and all movies by that director? That's inefficient, since you only care about cosine similarities between one director's work and one move.

Comment: I thought cosine_similarity(tf_idf_dir_matrix, tf_idf_dir_matrix) would compute similarity between all movies by that director and all movies by that director. I am interested in finding out similar movies by a director.